# Is there function like Console.ReadKey in Spectre.Console.AnsiConsole?

Tags: c#, console-application, spectre.console

Hi i was wondering if there is a function like Console.ReadKey() but with use of AnsiConsole from Spectre.Console package for c#, i dont know if i should use regular one from Console namespace?

I tried something like that but i dont know if Console is integrated with AnsiConsole

```
 AnsiConsole.Write("Press any key to continue");
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not, perhaps the following would suit your requirement. Change colors to suit you needs.

```
private static void Render(Rule rule)
{
    AnsiConsole.Write(rule);
    AnsiConsole.WriteLine();
}

private static void ExitPrompt()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Render(new Rule($"[yellow]Press Enter to exit[/]").RuleStyle(Style.Parse("silver")).Centered());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: So it is safe to use Console with AnsiConsole? I thought that this would lead to undefined behaviour in some cases, like not using standard terminal?

Comment: Been using both with zero issues,

Comment: AnsiConsole.Console.Input.ReadKey

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following snippet:

```cs
AnsiConsole.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
AnsiConsole.Console.Input.ReadKey(false);
```